# How to redirect to callback url after sign in using next-auth@beta v5 on next.js 14?

Tags: next-auth, next.js14

I have a protected route '/new'. Whenever I try to visit this '/new' route, it redirects me to the '/login' route to log in using the Google provider. After I log in, the callback URL is '/new', but instead of redirecting to '/new', it redirects to '/' which is my home route.

I just follow the instruction of [next.js learn](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-authentication) by adding this file and code:

/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
export { GET, POST } from '@/auth'
```

/auth.config.ts

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth'
import Google from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login'
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user
      // const isOnDashboardRoutes = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/')
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname === '/'
      const isOnNew = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/new')
      if (isOnDashboard || isOnNew) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true
        return false // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/', nextUrl))
      }
      return true
    }
  },
  // Add providers with an empty array for now
  providers: [Google]
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
```

/auth.ts

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import { authConfig } from './auth.config'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter'

import prisma from '@/lib/prismadb'

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut
} = NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: { strategy: 'jwt' },
  ...authConfig
})
```

/middleware.ts

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import { authConfig } from '@/auth.config'

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth

export const config = {
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)']
}
```

/action.ts

```
export async function login() {
  await signIn('google')
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Comment: watch the master class of nextjs auth by code with antonio